# How to scrape specific information from an element using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the url text https://dcr.alleghenycounty.us/Wills/Search/DOCUMENTS/WRV1160000053A.pdf from this element:
[image]
but so far all the guides I've found only explain how to get the 'inner text' of the element, which doesn't help me here. If anyone knows how to get the specific link contained in src="", the information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is stopping you from using vanila javascript? Find the dom element and grab the `src`, this should be easy.

Here is how you can apply it.

```
const pdfUrl = await page.evaluate(()=>document.getElementById("plugin").src)
```